# Is Perl worth learning as a beginner

Tags: perl

I know this isn't the type of question people care about, but as someone who is getting into coding, I was wondering if I should get into Perl early?

Answer (score 2):

Try it for a bit. If you don't like it, switch to something else. That "it" could be any language though. You don't have to stick with any particular language. Perl, in particular, suits people who have dabbled in lots of different languages since it's a stew of stolen ideas.

It might be easier for you to think about the sorts of things you want to do in the wide, wide universe of "programming". Then, find the people who are doing that and see what they use. Try that. If you don't like it, move on to something else.

As you go on in your career, think about trying programming languages from the major types: procedural, object-oriented, functional, or whatever label people want to give these things. Get different perspectives and approaches to problems. Everything you experience puts more tools in your toolbox, and when you run into a problem, you can select whatever best works for that situation.